# Xamarin Webview did not load this specific source url in UWP projekt

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

Xamarin.Forms Webview did not load a specific url im UWP projekt.
If I try the same with Android it works fine...

XAML:

```
ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WebViewTest.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <WebView HeightRequest="600"  WidthRequest="800" x:Name="webView"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Code-behind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace WebViewTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

           webView.Source = @"https://player.twitch.tv/?allowfullscreen=false&autoplay=true&channel=EtcKid&parent=streamernews.example.com";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem first appeared about 2 weeks ago.

I use Xamarin.Forms: v4.8.0.1364 and VisualStudio 2019: v16.7.2

Does anyone have any solutions ?

Greetings and thanks,

Timon

Comment: Welcome to SO! Hi, it seems not works in UWP. I will continue to research it , if good news will update here .

Answer (score 0):

According to [Xamarin WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#performance):

> The UWP WebView uses the Microsoft Edge rendering engine. Desktop and
> tablet devices should see the same performance as using the Edge
> browser itself.

UWP WebView is using the legacy Microsoft Edge rendering engine, so I tested with Microsoft Edge legacy, and the website can't be open in it. It should be the problem with Edge legacy.

There is WebView2 which supportsMicrosoft Edge(Chromium), but it's only in WinUI 3 preview, which hasn't been integrated into stable UWP yet, for more information, please check:

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback/issues/186

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Comment: Many thanks for your response.
I've tested it with webview2 and it works fine.
However, webview2 is beta and not suitable for production ...

Comment: @Timon My pleasure. And yes it's in preview which is not recommended in production. Just checked the WinUI roadMap: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/roadmap and https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/docs/roadmap.md WebView2 is quite close to release, and you can subscribe to this github repo to get the latest news of WebView2: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Announcements

Comment: how do you use webview2 in XF?